# Derivation of Lyapunov exponent in 1D disordered system

Tags: solid-state-physics, complex-systems, tight-binding, disorder

What I am considering is a tight-binding model of 1D disordered system. According to the [literature](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/56/12/001/meta) (page 1500, equation (60)), Lyapunov exponent $\gamma$ is calculated as follows which I am not totally familiar with. (Looks like it is not derived from transfer matrix method.)
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \lim_{j\to\infty}-\frac{\ln(a^{2}_{j} + a^{2}_{j+1})}{2j}
\end{equation}
From the above equation, $a_{j}$ is an amplitude of the wave-function associated with the lattice site $j$. Are there any reference that consider the derivation of the above formula? If not, help on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really my turf, but looking for these things one stumbles upon Furstenberg-Kesten theorem and sources such as [this](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-82-04913-4), [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/73983828.pdf), [this](http://wwwteor.mi.infn.it/~molinari/TESI/tesi_Ciarchi.pdf), and [this](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pram/058/02/0155-0172) (the last 3 are pdfs), which hopefully might be of use, if you don't know them yet.

Comment: @stafusa Thank you for the comment! I will check those pdf that you have recommended : )